# xamarin stacklayout child removes itself

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, stacklayout

I have a simple `Stacklayout` that shows Buttons.
I want to be able to let children remove itself from the `stacklayout`.

this project is just for testing purposes, so every button is linked to the same event-handler.

```
private void Button_Pressed_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    stack.Children.RemoveAt(stack.Children.Count - 1);
}
```

everything's fine until one button removes itself, then the following unsupported error appears:

Unhandled Exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ButtonRenderer from native
>   handle 0xbfb79bfc (key_handle 0x3e59524).

Has anyone an idea how to accomplish this? Since it's a `nonSupportedException` a simple try & catch didn't do the job

EDIT: 
I got it working, i registered the eventhandler to the Pressed-Event. Appearently that was the problem, when using the Clicke-Event everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What 's version of Xamarin which you are using? I tried with Xamarin.Form 3.0.0.561731 and it worked well.
Please check my code as bellow:

Xaml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RemoveItSelf"
             x:Class="RemoveItSelf.MainPage">

    <StackLayout x:Name="stack">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Button Text="Remove" Clicked="PressMeButton_Clicked"></Button>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Xaml.cs page:

```
namespace RemoveItSelf
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PressMeButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //stack.Children.RemoveAt(0);
            stack.Children.RemoveAt(stack.Children.Count - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also installed version 3.0.0.561731

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked. I don't get it why in my project the exception keeps getting raised

Comment: Please share your xaml page also